# Valgrind Suppression file for Mac OS X 10.8.3

Tags: macos, valgrind, suppression

I'm testing a third party library on Mac OS X with Valgirnd. I'm seeing lots of findings from OS X stuff, which is drowning issues with the library I am interested in (OS X appears to generate about 900 of these):

```
...
==11472== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==11472==    at 0x7FFF5FC1E238: _simple_salloc (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==11472==    by 0x7FFF5FC016E5: dyld::mkstringf(char const*, ...) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==11472==    by 0x7FFF5FC0AC07: dlsym (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==11472==    by 0xB1E75: dlsym (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==11472==    by 0x1001B6D82: dbxInitLDAP (in ./testlib)
==11472==    by 0xB27E0: (below main) (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==11472== 
==11472== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==11472==    at 0x7FFF5FC1E23F: _simple_salloc (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==11472==    by 0x7FFF5FC016E5: dyld::mkstringf(char const*, ...) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==11472==    by 0x7FFF5FC0AC07: dlsym (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==11472==    by 0xB1E75: dlsym (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==11472==    by 0x1001B6D82: dbxInitLDAP (in ./testlib)
==11472==    by 0xB27E0: (below main) (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
...
```

Does anyone have a Valgrind suppression file for Mac OS X 10.8.3 they could share? Or is anyone aware of a free/open source project that supplies one?

Comment: This isn't an answer per se, but you should update to the latest SVN version of Valgrind. Until such time as a Valgrind 3.11.x release is made, the significant recent improvements in Valgrind on OS X are only available through the latest SVN code.